# Parse the string response using key value pair and add them in map or array

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am getting a response which has key value pairs separated by `:`

```
USER: 0xbb492894B403BF08e9181e42B07f76814b10FEdc
IP: 10.0.2.6
NETMASK: 255.255.0.0
SUPERNODE: tlcsupernode.ddns.net
PORT: 5000
COMMUNITY: tlcnet
PSK: mysecret
MAC: 00:02:ff:00:02:06
```

To parse and store them, I am using the below code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] parts = response.trim().split(":");

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
    map.put(parts[i], parts[i + 1]);
}

for (String s : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(s + " is " + map.get(s));
    Log.d("Testing", "  "+s + " is " + map.get(s));
}
```

But as the MAC has multiple times `:` separator, I am not able to parse it properly.

I got the help from the below link:
[Split string into key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153753/split-string-into-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Are you using one response String, or is each pair a Single string?

Comment: one response string. Not the each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java 8 streams, you can do it as a one liner.

```
String resp = "USER: 0xbb492894B403BF08e9181e42B07f76814b10FEdc\n" + 
        "IP: 10.0.2.6\n" + 
        "NETMASK: 255.255.0.0\n" + 
        "SUPERNODE: tlcsupernode.ddns.net\n" + 
        "PORT: 5000\n" + 
        "COMMUNITY: tlcnet\n" + 
        "PSK: mysecret\n" + 
        "MAC: 00:02:ff:00:02:06";

Map<String, String> map = Arrays.asList(resp.split("\\R")).stream().map(x -> x.split(":", 2)).collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x[0], x -> x[1].trim()));

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Prints,

```
Key: SUPERNODE, Value: tlcsupernode.ddns.net
Key: NETMASK, Value: 255.255.0.0
Key: COMMUNITY, Value: tlcnet
Key: PORT, Value: 5000
Key: IP, Value: 10.0.2.6
Key: PSK, Value: mysecret
Key: USER, Value: 0xbb492894B403BF08e9181e42B07f76814b10FEdc
Key: MAC, Value: 00:02:ff:00:02:06
```

Here, `\\R` (matches any type of newline) splits your response string with newline which further gets split using `:` with second parameter as 2 to split the string to get max two values, and finally gets collected as `Map` using `Collectors.toMap`

**Edit:**

For older version of Java, you can use a simple for loop,

```
String resp = "USER: 0xbb492894B403BF08e9181e42B07f76814b10FEdc\n" + "IP: 10.0.2.6\n" + "NETMASK: 255.255.0.0\n"
        + "SUPERNODE: tlcsupernode.ddns.net\n" + "PORT: 5000\n" + "COMMUNITY: tlcnet\n" + "PSK: mysecret\n"
        + "MAC: 00:02:ff:00:02:06";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String line : resp.split("\\R")) {
    String[] keyValue = line.split(":", 2);
    map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am using Android. Java 8 supports I am not getting for API level 15.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee: I've added code using simple forloop which should work fine in old Java versions.

Comment: Nice and easy to use solution using `split` twice!

Comment: This worked for me. I was missing the double split!!. Thanks Pushpesh.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
String[] parts = response.trim().split(":");
```

Do this:

```
String[] parts = response.trim().split(":", 2);
```

That `2` at the end will force the string to be split into only two substrings.  Using no additional parameter like you're doing currently means "split into an unlimited number of substrings".

Also, you should trim the keys and values before storing them in case there are spaces around the initial `':'`

One caveat:  This assumes that the additional `':'` characters will always occur in the value, and not in the key.

---

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your split regex to `:\\s|\\n`. With this the code you are using should work as expected.

Another solution is to split by `\\R` first and handle each line separately. For this you either can use `line.split(":", 2)` or `line.split(":\\s")`. If you need a more flexible solution you can use a regex to process each line.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>.+):\\s+(?<value>.+)");
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String line : response.split("\\R")) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
    }
}
```

For Java 8 and above you can use the Stream API:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>.+):\\s+(?<value>.+)");
Map<String, String> map2 = Arrays.stream(response.split("\\R"))
        .map(pattern::matcher)
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.group("key"), m -> m.group("value")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of colon followed by whitespace does seem to be unique, at least in the sample data you showed us.  So, try splitting on that:

```
String[] parts = response.split(":\\s+");
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```